# How to prevent Devise from auto logout user on specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authentication, sign, out

I have devise-based auth system on my RoR-site, and I need to auto sign out user after some time of inactivity. But also I have some pages on my site, that created to be opened for long time (user will just watch to page, where info is updated by ajax) and I want to NOT sign out user when this page is opened.

Is anybody has a idea how to do that? Or how to tell Devise that ajax request is a user activity too?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have devise 1.5.2 installed, if not, upgrade it, its been 6 months at this question :-) and I hope you already solved the problem.

You can change the timeout_in return value when you are at the page you want to prevent auto signout at.

For example:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
      if session[:auto_sign_out] then
         #the normal period of signout
         30.minutes
      else
         #very long period, to prevent sign-out
         100.years
      end
  end
end
```

Then, you can easily add a before_filter at ApplicationController to set the `session[:auto_sign_out]` value

like this:

```
before_filter :manage_page_auto_sign_out


def manage_page_auto_sign_out
# check the params, and see if the id is the id of the specific page
if params[:id] == EXCLUDED_PAGE_ID then
session[:auto_sign_out]= false
else
session[:auto_sign_out]= true
end
end
```

additionally, you can add other conditions to make sure that you are checking against the page you want, by checking the controller name of page like this:

```
def manage_page_auto_sign_out
# check the params, and see if the id is the id of the specific page
if controller_name == 'pages' && params[:id] == EXCLUDED_PAGE_ID then
session[:auto_sign_out]= false
else
session[:auto_sign_out]= true
end
end
```

you need to check the name of the page controller, I hope this helps

Comment: Hm, that does not work cause you cannot access to session in a model class (Student):
undefined local variable or method `session'